# SQL tables Joins and generating new column based on query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables

- transaction
- product
- date

Transaction table has columns

- `date_id, prod_id,spend_amt, qty, transaction_fid` .

Product table has

- `prod_id, desc, category`

and date table has

- `date_id, week_id` .

I need to flag products `active` if they are sold in last 4 weeks else `non-active` 
How to go about this.

Comment: what you have tried Please explain? What is week id ?Please explain with some data

Comment: `week_id ` is the unique indicator for each week. What I tried is to find count of `transaction_fid` for every product in where week_id is in the range of `201815 -201818` .

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: transaction, product, date, transaction_fid are 4 tables...

Comment: Heh, I find it kinda perculiar that there's a foreign key used that links to a date table.  More commonly you would just see a DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP in the table, and the "calendar" table would have a primary key on a DATE type field. Unless of course that date_id is a DATE in this case, and not an INT.

Comment: where is the join to date table??

Answer (score 1):

Use an `EXISTS` clause to check whether a transaction in a date range exists for a product.

```
select
  p.*
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from transaction t
    join date d on d.date_id = t.date_id
    where t.prod_id = p.prod_id
    and d.week_id between 201815 and 201818
  ) then 1 else 0 end as is_active
from product p;
```

It is strange not to see any date in your tables. In your request you are asking for the last four weeks, which is not possible without knowing a transaction's date of course. In your request comments, however, you say you want to look at the range `week_id between 201815 and 201818`, so I used this.

Answer (score 0):

If you left join to the product_id's that have a transaction in the last 4 weeks then you could use a CASE for the flag.

Example:

```
SELECT p.*
, (CASE WHEN wk4.prod_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS isActive
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t.prod_id
  FROM Transaction t
  JOIN "date" d ON d.date_id = t.date_id
  WHERE d.week_id >= to_number(to_char(current_date-(7*4), 'YYYYWW'))
  GROUP BY t.prod_id
) wk4 ON wk4.prod_id = p.prod_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the way to do this.

```
SELECT pr.prod_id, (case when count(distinct tr.transaction_fid)>=1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end) as active_flag
FROM transaction tr
INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.prod_id = tr.prod_id 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date_id, week_id
    FROM date
    WHERE week_id BETWEEN 201815 AND 201818
) d ON d.date_id = tr.date_id
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `GROUP BY pr.prod_id`. And the `INNER JOIN` only shows you products in the given range (i.e. active_flag = 'Y'), so you won't find any other products. You would need an outer join instead. But I wouldn't join anyway. Use `EXISTS` to check whether a transaction exists in the data range for a product. Please see my answer on this.